# TinyMCE Automatically Adding formatting

Tags: tinymce

I've been using tinymce in sites for years and never had this issue. Whenever I return it adds the following in front of my paragraph tag.

I'm using the latest version: 3.5.8

```
<div style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;">
```

Here's my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        force_p_newlines : true
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes just posting a question seeds the solution in your head!!

Here's how I fixed it. In the css file javascript/tinymce/themes/simple/skin/default/content.css I commented out:

```
body, td, pre {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
}

body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

That did it!